# undefined is not a constructor in Mocha / Chai / Sinon on PhantomJS with Array.prototype.find

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phantomjs, mocha.js, chai

I'm at serious head scratching point with this now. I have a line of code in a method I'm trying to test which I just cannot get to pass whatever I do. It works! There is nothing wrong with it in 'the real world'.

I find everytime I delve into JS Unit Testing I hit snags like this and it makes me wonder if it's really worth it.

Here's the method I'm trying to test...

```
    _mapStopsAroundHub(managerContext, soCode, homePostcode, homeStops, changeLinkedStopCallback) {
    homeStops = homeStops || [];
    MappingDataGateway.getNearbyStops(soCode, homePostcode, Cfg.DefaultNearbyStopDistance, (stops, status, xhr) => {
        if(status == MappingDataGateway.Status.OK) {
            stops.forEach((element) => {
                let isHomeStop = homeStops.length > 0 && (homeStops.find(hs => hs.id === element.id) !== undefined);
                let markerColor = isHomeStop ? "green" : "orange";
                let marker = managerContext.addBusStopMarker(element, markerColor);
                if (changeLinkedStopCallback) {
                    managerContext._api.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
                        let newIcon = marker.icon.includes("orange") ? `/images/fa-bus-green.png` : `/images/fa-bus-orange.png`;
                        marker.setIcon(newIcon);
                        changeLinkedStopCallback(marker.data);
                    })
                }
            });
        }
        else if (errorCallback) { errorCallback(xhr); }
    });
}
```

I've added the 'isHomeStop' variable and the totally unnecessary homeSTops.length check to let some of the test cases pass but I can't test the case where the homeStops array contains data as Mocha falls over with it's ever so helpful error message 'undefined is not a constructor' type messages. The full error is as follows...

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) MapsManager can interract with a loaded map to map the stops around a hub point directly with a linked stop mapping all selectable stops in the area showing selected linked stops in a different colour FAILED
>           undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'homeStops.find(function (hs) {
>                                       return hs.id === element.id;
>                                   })')

The test that's failing looks like this...

```
  it("directly with a linked stop mapping all selectable stops in the area showing selected linked stops in a different colour", () => {
            let allStops = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
            let homeStops = [{ id: 2 }];
            let mappingDataStub = Sinon.stub(MappingDataGateway, 'getNearbyStops');
            mappingDataStub.yields(allStops, "OK");
            let addMarkerStub = Sinon.stub(objUt, 'addBusStopMarker');

            objUt._mapStopsAroundHub(objUt, testSoCode, testPostCode, homeStops);
            mappingDataStub.restore();
            addMarkerStub.restore();

            Sinon.assert.calledThrice(addMarkerStub);
            Sinon.assert.calledWith(addMarkerStub, allStops[0], "orange");
            Sinon.assert.calledWith(addMarkerStub, allStops[1], "green");
            Sinon.assert.calledWith(addMarkerStub, allStops[2], "orange");
        });
```

I've put undefined checks in the code to check the state of the object and it's there - it seems that it's falling over on the lambda expression within find.

ADDITIONAL INFO: This only seems to happen with PhantomJS - If I use Chrome all runs fine (although this isn't a viable CI option!).

Comment: Are you using `new` anywhere in your code? Sounds likely that the line number in the error message is wrong

Comment: Probably in various places in my code but not in the method that I'm testing. The error message clearly points at the transpiled version of the 6th line of the method that I'm testing. If anything ever goes wrong it's one of the few error messages Mocha ever seems to produce. I don't know if it's a transpilation thing of if Mocha / Chai / Sinon is just a pile of junk and I should go back to using Jasmine. It's a massive overhaul to do that though at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhantomJS likely doesn't support Array.prototype.find. Add in a polyfill in a test helpers file and it will solve your issue. [Polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Nice one! I found this out at exactly the same time (you can have the answer vote though!)

Comment: No prob, PhantomJS is a pain, you'll likely find more stuff that doesn't work too. Enjoy!

Comment: Oh joys! (JS unit testing is such a love / hate thing for me)

Comment: faced the same issue with mocha. Thanks for the answer, saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an issue with PhantomJS.

I fixed it by applying a PhantomJS polyfil from here...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-polyfill-find

(sucks....)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [latest version 2.5b](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads) which has an up-todate Webkit abd fully supports ES6.

Comment: That sounds nice but I don't think it'll fit in my NPM dependency tree with Karma so it'll end up being useless when it hits Azure for the CI builds (I'd rather have it fall over in a heap locally first). It looks like polyfills are my way forward for now.